# How do I access the related ForeignKey object from a object in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example,

I have an object mapped to a table. IE:

```
location = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
```

When I do object.location, I get the actual foreignkey value. But I don't want that, how can I get the object instead (like in Django ORM). Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using declarative base objects (which is recommended if you want it more like Django) then:

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child", backref="parents")
```

See the [relationship docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html)

Comment: If that's the answer you were looking for can you "Accept" it?

Comment: It looks like you don't need the first **Parent**